# React useState on page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make edit page for my form.
I am using useState hook to keep data from fields. I would like to display current values, when I edit specific product, but when I renew page I am getting value as undefined:
[image]

This is my code:

```
const [orderForm, setOrderForm] = React.useState({
        title: {
            elementType: 'input',
            label: 'Title',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Title'
            },
            value: `${product ? product.title : ''}`,
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        price: {
            elementType: 'input',
            label: 'Price',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Price'
            },
            value: `${product ? product.price : ''}`,
            validation: {
                required: true,
                isNumeric: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
        category: {
            elementType: 'select',
            label: 'Select category',
            defaultValue: 'Select category',
            value: `${product ? product.category : ''}`,
            validation: {
                required: false
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },

        description: {
            elementType: 'textarea',
            label: 'Description',
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: 'Description'
            },
            value: `${product ? product.description : ''}`,
            validation: {
                required: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false
        },
    });
```

How can I keep values for my inputs on page refresh? Thank you!

Comment: What is `product` at the time this state is set?

Comment: @DBS Its an object: Product { category: "Second"
description: "klklklkklllll"
imageUrl: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABGoA"
price: 2121212
status: "published"
title: "netley"
_id: "5ff2b63ca00f52184f7a0522" }

Comment: Just save data to the database and request them on refresh.

Comment: Or, if it's temp before the user submitted the form, store them in the localStorage